# Обозначение осей вне графиков

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Каким образом можно добавить такое обозначение графиков? Слева внизу нарисовал. Сам код:

```py
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    rc = {"font.family" : "serif", 
          "mathtext.fontset" : "stix"}
    plt.rcParams.update(rc)
    plt.rcParams["font.serif"] = ["Times New Roman"] + plt.rcParams["font.serif"]
    plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 10
    plt.subplots()
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3, constrained_layout=True)
    for ax in axs.flat:
        pcm = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random((20, 20)))
    fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=[axs[2, 2]], location='bottom')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737736/matplotlib-axis-arrow-tip?rq=1) есть детальное описание, как нанести стрелки на оси графиков, в частности за счет данной функции:

```
def arrowed_spines(fig, ax):

xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim() 
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()

# get width and height of axes object to compute 
# matching arrowhead length and width
dps = fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted()
bbox = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(dps)
width, height = bbox.width, bbox.height

# manual arrowhead width and length
hw = 1./20.*(ymax-ymin) 
hl = 1./20.*(xmax-xmin)
lw = 1. # axis line width
ohg = 0.3 # arrow overhang

# compute matching arrowhead length and width
yhw = hw/(ymax-ymin)*(xmax-xmin)* height/width 
yhl = hl/(xmax-xmin)*(ymax-ymin)* width/height

# draw x and y axis
ax.arrow(xmin, 0, xmax-xmin, 0., fc='k', ec='k', lw = lw, 
         head_width=hw, head_length=hl, overhang = ohg, 
         length_includes_head= True, clip_on = False) 

ax.arrow(0, ymin, 0., ymax-ymin, fc='k', ec='k', lw = lw, 
         head_width=yhw, head_length=yhl, overhang = ohg, 
         length_includes_head= True, clip_on = False)
```

В вашем случае код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rc = {"font.family" : "serif", 
        "mathtext.fontset" : "stix"}
plt.rcParams.update(rc)
plt.rcParams["font.serif"] = ["Times New Roman"] + plt.rcParams["font.serif"]
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 10
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3, constrained_layout=True)
for ax in axs.flat:
    pcm = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random((20, 20)))
    arrowed_spines(fig, ax) # вызов функции, указанной выше
fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=[axs[2, 2]], location='bottom')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интересует отдельное расположение. В том месте, где я и нарисовал. Чтобы подписать название осей.

Comment: Теперь понял. Тогда мой ответ не по теме :)